# 8086 assembly language - What happened to the stack space when I change the value of ss?

Tags: assembly, cpu, masm, x86-16, dosbox

I want to move the data in

```
1000:0000~1000:0007 to 
1000:0008~1000:000F
```

so I set the registers like this:

> ds = 1000
>   ss = 1000
>   sp = 0010

So I think I can use the `PUSH` instruction like:

```
 push [6]
 push [4]
 push [2]
 push [0]
```

to achieve this. But when `push [6]` has been executed, I found that the data in 1000:0000~1000:0007 has partly be changed.

Why?

Comment: Presumably because an interrupt happened and used your stack. It's a bad idea to do it this way, any particular reason?

Comment: Use [`movsw`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVS:MOVSB:MOVSW:MOVSD:MOVSQ.html) or [`rep movsw`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/REP:REPE:REPZ:REPNE:REPNZ.html) to copy blocks of memory.  (Or since you're using DOSBOX, you can use 386 extensions, not just the base 8086 instruction set like if you were stuck using emu8086).  A couple 32-bit load and stores with MOV instructions will be more efficient than setting up pointers for MOVSD or MOVSW for small copies.

Comment: As @Jester says, DOS is a primitive OS. It has only one stack for the OS and user programs. The timer interrupt runs every 18.2ms. It pushes and pops state info on the stack. Other interrupts can also occur. So a few words below the current ss:sp will be constantly changing. The moral is, don't write a program that mucks with the stack unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/4957/the-stack/17507/zilog-z80-stack#t=201612102342441739113 - notice the comments in ASCII art about values ahead of `sp`. (it's Z80 article, but this applies 1:1 to 16b x86)

Comment: I'm just a beginner of assembly language and tried it just for practice.